# Passar valor do javascript para o post do php

Tags: php, javascript, api, post, google

Estou tendo problemas para pegar a minha localização e passar para o post do php com `onload`. Como posso fazer isso ? Os valores que estou tentando capturar são a **lat** e **long** do google.

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 6
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

  // Try HTML5 geolocation.
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }
}
```

Comment: Faz um request assíncrono passando os valores, se você estver utilizando jquery, pode usar o `$.post `

Comment: mas o que não ta conseguindo fazer? Pegar a localização(lat, lng) do google maps, ou enviar esses dados para o php?

Comment: passar as coordenadas para o php.

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo de como você pode fazer com jquery.ajax (tem no site oficial a documentação) [api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
})
.done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```